# cloned a git repository from github - how do i create a new github repository into a repository into my account

Tags: git, github

I did a: 
git clone http://github/anotheruser/something.git my-space

and made some changes. Is there anyway I can create a git repository in my account and commit my changes to it? I am aware I should have forked.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to fork the repository on GitHub, and then edit the `.git/config` file in your local copy so that `origin` points to your newly forked repository instead of the original one. You should then be able to push to it as normal.

If you prefer, you can use this command instead of editing the file:

```
git remote set-url origin <YOUR-REPO-URL>
```

Comment: I did this but is there any way I can confirm the url that it thinks it should be sending to?

Comment: @timpone: You can do a `git push --dry-run`.

Comment: still having problems with this - it's prompting me for uname and pwd whereas my other repositories are set up with ssh keys. Would it be easier / make sense to just make another remote and push to that?

Comment: @timpone: I don't see how that would make any difference. Did you remember to use the version of the URL with write access (`git@github.com:username/repo.git`)?

Comment: thx hammar - this was my fault - had a typo. thx for your help